# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter python 3.7.2 windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pip

i know there have already been many such questions asked on this forum but i couldnt find any that helped my particular case.

i am trying to install tkinter(and some other packages) using pip install on windows 10 cmd. but it gives the error

```
pip install tkinter

 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from 
versions: )
No matching distribution found for tkinter
```

how do i install it? i get the same error for some other packages too. what is the solution that works for any and all future packages i install?

Comment: You cannot install tkinter with pip. It normally is bundled with python.

Answer (score 5):

When installing packages with `pip`, it automatically collects any dependencies of these packages, if they aren't already installed. For example, if you install `SciPy`and you haven't installed `NumPy`, pip will automatically install `NumPy`, because it is listed in `SciPy`'s dependencies.

The error you got happens, when one of the listed requirements of the package you want to install is not availible. This can have a number of causes:

- The required package is not availible on PyPi.
- The required package or the package you want to install is not compatible with your version of python.
- You typed the wrong package name.

When i try `pip install tkinter`, i get the same error. The reason for that is that tkinter is already included in the python standard library (at least for python 3.x). You shouldn't have to install it. You can verify that tkinter is working by a simple example like

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: when i try to install any of the other already install packages, i dont get any error, just a simple message of requirement already satisfied.
and i get the above mentioned error for some other packages too

Comment: such as pyqt or pygui

Comment: For installing PyQt, what command did you use? it works fine for me with `pip install PyQt5`.

Comment: yes tkinter is already installed and running.
nevermind pyqt. was using wrong command